# Puppet: hiera hash keys based on hostname never retrieves value

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am using a Hiera hash to hold some token values which are host-specific. the keys within the hash correspond to the hostname/certname of the node(s) that'll be classified with the profile module that calls the hash value. However, when I apply the module, the value which corresponds to the hash key for the host is always null. Here's the code I'm working with.

in hiera-file.yaml

```
token_lookup:
  host-name1: 'abcdef123'
  host-name2: 'abbcde456'
```

and in profile.pp

```
$_tokens = hiera_hash('token_lookup', undef, 'hiera-file')
$_specific_token = $_tokens["${::hostname}"]       <== never gets a value
```

I'm certain that the hostname matches the key in the hash. The question is, what's the right syntax here for getting the value from the hiera-file to populate properly? Thank you in advance for the advice.

**edit: I believe I have discovered an issue when the hash key has a literal '-' character in it, as many hostnames do. I updated the hash to show keys with dashes in it, and should now ask a more specific question:  I see dozens of articles about how to escape characters in the values of hashes by using double quotes, but I don't see anything - even on yaml.org - about how to escape the character if it appears as part of the key.  Any tips on this issue?  A YAML parser shows that this is valid syntactically, but I believe it is treating the '-' as a collection marker instead of a literal character.**

Comment: Have you made sure that the file is used at all? That you are picking up *any* data? Have you run with debug mode enabled? Used the `hiera` CLI for debugging?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the normal lookup values function just fine; it's only this one that doesn't get populated like I'd expect.  Will try the hiera CLI - appreciate the tip

Comment: Have you tried quoting the hash keys?

Comment: sadly, yes, I have tried that to no avail despite the notion that a YAML parser thinks it's perfectly ok syntax. I think at this point I will settle for individual yaml files based on `${::certname}` since that's the most-specific hiera scope in my puppet master hiera config, but that's what I was hoping to avoid (potentially many, many yaml files with 1 k-v pair).

Comment: Weird. I'm quite positive that I've used dashes in YAML hash keys before. There is one answer that indicates that the code should work. I recommend another round of careful debugging before you commit to a sledgehammer workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, I test it as below, seems it didn't target the right yaml file in your environment. Check the hierarchy setting, and put the token `key-value` in the right place.

If I put the yaml file to global.yaml(If hiera can't find the key, it will always go to the last one in my hiera.yaml setting)

I rebuilt it with simplest setting:

```
$ cat /etc/hiera.yaml:

---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /var/lib/hiera on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\hiera\var on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:

$ cat /var/lib/hiera/global.yaml
token_lookup:
  host-name1: 'abcdef123'
  host-name2: 'abbcde456'

$ cat profile.pp   
$_tokens = hiera_hash('token_lookup', undef, 'hiera-file')
notice ("tokens is $_tokens")
$_specific_token = $_tokens["${::hostname}"]
notice ("token is $_specific_token ")
```

Then I run `puppet apply`, I can see the result

```
$ FACTER_hostname='host-name1' puppet apply profile.pp --hiera_config /etc/hiera.yaml
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): tokens is host-name1abcdef123host-name2abbcde456
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): token is abcdef123
Notice: Compiled catalog for host-name1 in environment production in 0.04 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds

$ FACTER_hostname='host-name2' puppet apply profile.pp --hiera_config /etc/hiera.yaml
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): tokens is host-name1abcdef123host-name2abbcde456
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): token is abbcde456
Notice: Compiled catalog for host-name2 in environment production in 0.04 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
root@ac976d6d79fb:~#
```

Comment: thanks for the sanity check; I don't have access to the master, but other variables in the module are getting their values from the same hiera file and are read properly, so I'm convinced that the catalog compilation is finding the correct yaml file.  I will continue debugging; agree that it _should_ work

Answer (score 0):

I think [hiera_hash](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#hiera-lookup-functions) is not what you want.

> **hiera_hash**:
>       Uses a hash merge lookup. Expects every value in the hierarchy for a given key to be a hash, and merges the top-level keys in each hash into a single hash. Note that this does not do a deep-merge in the case of nested structures.

Change:

```
$_tokens = hiera_hash('token_lookup', undef, 'hiera-file')
```

to

```
$_tokens = hiera('token_lookup', {}) #it will create empty hash if it couldn't find 'token_lookup' variable.
```

Please also check the following [example:](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#interacting-with-structured-data-from-hiera)

```
# /etc/puppet/hieradata/appservers.yaml
---
proxies:
  - hostname: lb01.example.com
    ipaddress: 192.168.22.21
  - hostname: lb02.example.com
    ipaddress: 192.168.22.28

# Get the structured data:
$proxies = hiera('proxies')
# Index into the structure:
$use_ip = $proxies[1]['ipaddress'] # will be 192.168.22.28
```

Comment: Right, the example is an array of hashes.  The nested value(s) are accessed by key name - it's the same as what I'm doing, excepting that I have an interpolation token as the key to lookup. I've tried using the `hiera` priority lookup function in place of the hash merge and have the same result as using the hash merge.